# Duplicating data in ML training

Tags: machine-learning, computational-statistics

Lets say I have a data set $X_1...X_N$ with the corresponding class of each event $Y(0,1)$. I'm training this set and getting a result for classification.

What happens if I simply duplicate the entire set and feed that to my ML algorithm? the probability for every class is still the same. Should i expect a different result?

Thanks

Comment: It depends on algorithm you use. For Logistic Regression behaviour will be the same. For Random Forest it depends on realization, while generally due to randomness of the algorithm you will get a different model.

Answer (score 1):

This would depend on particular ML algorithm you are using. For some it may influence the outcome, for some it won't.

With most ML algorithms it won't matter how many times you feed in the learning set and in what order is it fed.

- For many algorithms it will yield exactly the same results.
- For some, the results will be different, but the difference should be relatively small. In general case feeding data in multiple times will *not improve* the efficiency of classification.

I recommend you try with RapidMinder with some dummy data and different classification algorithms and compare the classification error results using different algorithms and for both - feeding data in once and multiple times.